# How to remove xmlns:php from output in a XSL produced by `registerPHPFunctions`?

Tags: php, xml, xslt-1.0

Using updtodated PHP5 and libXML. See
[registerphpfunctions](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php).

I try many things... Including `saveXML(null,LIBXML_NSCLEAN)`.

Perhaps related to [Omit unneeded namespaces from the output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15582825/287948)

---

EXAMPLE OF XML:

```xml
<root><p>Hello</p><p>world</p></root>
```

EXAMPLE OF XSL:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="root"><foo>
   <xsl:for-each select="p">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="php:function('regFunction', . )" /></p>
   </xsl:for-each></foo>
</xsl:template>
```

EXAMPLE OF XML OUTPUT:

```
<foo>
   <p xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">Hello</p>
   <p xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">world</p>
</foo>
```

The `xmlns:php` is a overhead, it is not used at output!

Comment: Show us your code, show us the output, tell us how it differs from the expected output.

Comment: YES, the related question have the answer!

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/15583934/287948

Comment: DELETE QUESTION or stay for somebody put the answer here?

Comment: Why do you want an answer when you haven't provided any XML document and any XSLT code? In any such case the answer is: "This problem is due to the bad weather".

Comment: ok, there are a (edited)  "complete question".