# Omit unneeded namespaces from the output

Tags: xslt, output, xml-namespaces

My XSLT is outputiung some tags with `xmlns:x="http://something"` attribute... How to avoid this redundant attribute? The output XML never use, neither in a the `x:tag`, nor in an `x:attribute`.

---

EXAMPLE OF XML:

```xml
<root><p>Hello</p><p>world</p></root>
```

EXAMPLE OF XSL:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="root"><foo>
   <xsl:for-each select="p">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
   </xsl:for-each></foo>
   <xsl:for-each select="x">
    <link xlink:href="{x}" />
   </xsl:for-each></foo>
</xsl:template>
```

EXAMPLE OF XML OUTPUT:

```
<foo>
   <p xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">Hello</p>
   <p xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">world</p>
</foo>
```

The `xmlns:xlink` is a overhead, it is not used!

---

[A typical case](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php) where XSLT must use namespace but the output not:

```xml
 <xsl:value-of select="php:function('regFunction', . )" />
```

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide the source XML document and the transformation code. Without these one has to guess.

Comment: OK, I edited: sources for XML-IN, XSLT and XML-OUT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Dimitre has already said, if you are not using the `xlink` namespace anywhere in your XSLT, you should just remove its namespace declaration. If, however, your XSLT is actually using it somewhere that you haven't shown us, you can prevent it from being output by using the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xlink">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exclude-result-prefixes is the tool!  About the "... just remove its namespace declaration..." solution, I edited the question, for avoid this "trivial case".

Answer (score 0):

**Just remove this namespace declaration from the `xsl:stylesheet` instruction -- it isn't used (and thus necessary) at all**:

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

**The whole transformation now becomes**:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="no"/>

 <xsl:template match="root"><foo>
   <xsl:for-each select="p">
   <p class="a"><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
   </xsl:for-each></foo>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**and when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root><p>Hello</p><p>world</p></root>
```

**produces result that is free of namespaces**:

```
<foo>
    <p class="a">Hello</p>
    <p class="a">world</p>
</foo>
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited with a typical case. The other one is a `xsl:if` that is not used.

Comment: @PeterKrauss, exclude-result-prefixes="{}space-separated list of prefixes" can help in many cases. In other cases still one needs to remove the namespaces by code. BTW, I don't see any `xsl:if` in your posted code.

Comment: @PeterKrauss, Yes, in this specific case using the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute solves the problem. There are more tricky cases -- not on literal result elements, where one needs to actually prevent the copying of namespace nodes -- by code.